# A question in Diffferential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Looking to express this function in terms of the unit step function.

$$ f(t) = \begin{cases} t^2, & 0\le t<2, \\ 1, & t\ge 2. \end{cases} $$

My solution:

$$ f(t)= t^2[u(t-1)-u(t-2)] $$

wondering if my workings is correct, if not looking for some guidance

Comment: By unit step function I assume you mean that $u(t)=1$ for $t>0$ and $0$ otherwise? Then rather $t^2 u(t) - (t^2-1)u(t-2)$. Yours vanishes for large t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is zero for $t$ outside the interval $[1,2]$, which is not what you want. You want to multiply $t^2$ with a rectangular function, which is non-zero in the interval $[0,2]$, and you have to add a step function starting at $t=2$. This gives

$$f(t)=t^2[u(t)-u(t-2)]+u(t-2)$$

Comment: should the last part be u(t+2) or u(t-2)?

Comment: @javahelp: It must be $u(t-2)$ because it must start at $t=2$ (not at $t=-2$).

Answer (score 2):

@Matt L. Another solution is by using multiplication of step functions :

$$t^2.u(t).u(2-t)+u(t-2)$$

Comment: That's right: $u(t-t_1)-u(t-t_2)=u(t-t_1)u(t_2-t)$, $t_2>t_1$.